# Factoring a cubic

Tags: calculus, roots

I'm doing Calc 1 homework and it strikes me that when you have a cubic $x^3-5x+2$ and you put $-5x+2$ to one side and $x^3$ on the other you're essentially looking for where the graph of $x^3$ intersects with the graph of $-5x+2$. To put it into context the homework is asking us to find zeroes for the equation. Is there any equation that would let one evaluate where $x^3$ and $5x+2$ intersect?

Pardon me if this is kind of dumb. I'm beginning to share the little discoveries I make when I'm doing math and I have no gauge of whether they're worth anything to me or not. Talking about them with a community seems like the only way to truly gain an understanding.

Comment: This particular cubic has an easy to find integer root. Lookup the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

Comment: Whenever you work with a  equation of degree $3$, first try to find a root (test $-2, -1,1,2$) and then find the other two reduces to solve a equation of degree $2$ (as Siong did).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Observe that $2$ is a root of the polynomial. Hence,

$$x^3-5x+2=(x-2)q(x)$$

where $q$ is a quadratic term.

Btw, it should be intersection of $5x-2$ and $x^3$.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that q is a quadratic term?

Comment: $q$ is of the form of $ax^2+bx+c$.

Comment: I don't entirely understand the x-intercept written that way. I understand that (x-2) multiplied by q(x) would = 0 where x = 2 however I don't understand why a quadratic would would be represented rather than say the function where $f(x) = x^3-5x+2?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by $x$ intercept. We can write $x^3-5x+2 = (x-2)(ax^2+bx+c)$. We first find out what is $ax^2+bx+c$ then we can further factorize $ax^2+bx+c$.

Comment: Ahh I understand now! I didn't realize that a binomial multiplied by a quadratic is a cubic. And you're saying that once we divide the cubic by the binomial we get a quadratic and from there can further find the factors of the cubic? I guess I'm wrongly assuming that we're finding where f(x) = 0? where f(x) = x^3-5x+2

Comment: Usually we call $x-2$ a linear term. Yup, you have gotten the strategy.  We are indeed finding $f(x)=0$, once we factorize the polynomials, we get something like $(x-2)(x-c)(x-d)=0$, then the roots are $2, c, d$.